# python hierarchy from manager and employee id

Tags: python, hierarchy

I have a csv with two columns: employee id `'eid'` and manager's employee id `'mid'`. Trying to get python code that will, for each employee, add columns showing employee id's of the manager all the way to CEO. CEO has a an employee id of 1. Ultimately I want to write the result back to a csv.

So the data looks like:

```
eid,    mid
111,    112
113,    112
112,    114
114,    115
115,    1
```

I am expecting output that looks like this. Note that while no employee will have more than 4 levels of managers, but i would like to also learn python that names columns dynamically.

```
eid,    mid,    l2mid   l3mid   l4mid
111,    112,    114,    115,    1
113,    112,    114,    115,    1
112,    114,    115,    1   
114,    115,    1       
115,    1
```

I am very new to coding, and trying to teach myself but keep getting stuck. My questions: 
1) I was trying to use a for statement that took `mid` in a given row, then found that that manager's manager, and so on, until i reached the CEO. I have been trying along these lines:

```
df = pd.read_csv('employee.csv') 
if mid =! 1 
for i in df:
    df.['l2mid'] = df.loc[df.eid == [i], [mid]]
```

Maybe I'm approaching this backwards and I should try grouping all employees by manager? How would that code be different?

I have seen solutions in [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4855383/hierarchy-from-flat-data) and [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631381/sql-reports-for-manager-supervisor-employee-hierarchy-from-an-employee-table), and i've seen solutions that build [trees](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/261074/process-to-generate-hierarchical-structure-based-on-relational-data) and [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008860/create-nested-json-from-pandas-for-org-chart). I really appreciate any help and encouragement.

Update: next step was to add a country column - see: [entry here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45963576/python-write-value-from-dictionary-based-on-match-in-range-of-columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there is a better solution, but this works. I filled empty with zeros.

```
a = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    res = df[df['eid']==row['mid']]['mid'].values
    a.append(0 if not res else res[0])
df['l2mid'] = a

a = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    res = df[df['eid']==row['l2mid']]['mid'].values
    a.append(0 if not res else res[0])
df['l3mid'] = a

a = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    res = df[df['eid']==row['l3mid']]['mid'].values
    a.append(0 if not res else res[0])
df['l4mid'] = a

df
# output :
# eid   mid l2mid   l3mid   l4mid
# 0 111 112 114 115 1
# 1 113 112 114 115 1
# 2 112 114 115 1   0
# 3 114 115 1   0   0
# 4 115 1   0   0   0
```

You can define a function for routines.

```
def search_manager(target_column, new_column):
    a = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        res = df[df['eid']==row[target_column]]['mid'].values
        a.append(0 if not res else res[0])
    df[new_column] = a

search_manager('mid', 'l2mid')
search_manager('l2mid', 'l3mid')
search_manager('l3mid', 'l4mid')
```

Comment: Both of these approaches work - thank you! I need to study exactly why they work, but this is really helpful for me to make progress - both in my task and in my learning.

Comment: Can you explain this answer line by line. Thank you much!!